# Segmentation fault with a Sieve of Eratosthenes program

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I'm trying to implement the sieve algorithm where it'll ask for the size of a list of consecutive numbers and print out the prime numbers in that list, but I'm getting a seg fault: 11 error.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMIT 1000000 /*size of integers array*/

int main(void){
    char n[LIMIT];

    //Reads the size of integer array
    printf("Size of array:\n");
    if((fgets(n, LIMIT, stdin)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned long long int i,j;
    int *primes;
    int z = 1;

    primes = malloc(sizeof(n));

    for (i = 2; i < sizeof(n); i++){
    primes[i] = 1; //setting every number in list to 1
    }

    for (i = 2; i < sizeof(n); i++){
        if (primes[i]){
            for (j = i; (i*j) < sizeof(n); j++){
                primes[i * j] = 0; //remove multiples
            }
        } 
    }

    for (i = 2; i < sizeof(n); i++){
        if (primes[i]){
            printf("%dth prime = %llu\n",z++,i);
        }
    }

    free(primes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Noticed that you have not accepted any answers to your 5 previous posts.  Consider accepting an answer that well meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
char n[LIMIT];
```

With the value of `LIMIT` being `1000000`, that's a really big array (one million bytes). It would cause [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables). You need to dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
char *n = malloc(LIMIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is using `n` in a curious fashion.  Suggest simply scanning the the integer `n` and using `n` to end the loops rather than `sizeof(n)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned long n;

    //Reads the size of integer array
    buffer[30];
    printf("Size of array:\n");
    if((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (sscanf(buffer,"%lu", %n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to covert to a number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned long i,j;
    int *primes;
    // int z = 1;

    primes = malloc(n * sizeof *primes);

    for (i = 2; i < n; i++){
      primes[i] = 1; //setting every number in list to 1
    }

    for (i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if (primes[i]) {
            for (j = i; (i*j) < n; j++){
                primes[i * j] = 0; //remove multiples
            }
        } 
    }

    for (i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if (primes[i]){
            printf("%dth prime = %llu\n",z++,i);
        }
    }

    free(primes);
    return 0;
}
```